# Поиск и замена в xml из списка значений, находящихся в другом файле

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

1) В txt есть значения

```
160
170
180
190
```

2) есть xml

```
<cars>
<car><speed>aaa160bbb</speed></car>
<car><speed>ccc170ddd</speed></car>
<car><speed>eee180fff</speed></car>
<car><speed>ggg190hhh</speed></car>
```

Осуществить поиск значений из txt файла в xml файле и если нашлось, то заменить на 11111. Если не нашлось, то читать другое значение из txt

Должно получиться

```
<cars>
<car><speed>aaa11111bbb</speed></car>
<car><speed>ccc11111ddd</speed></car>
<car><speed>eee11111fff</speed></car>
<car><speed>ggg11111hhh</speed></car>
</cars>
```

И хотелось бы в winforms statusStrip чтобы в процессе поиска и замены выводился счетчик (как на скриншоте: Обработано элементов / всего элементов в txt):

[image: Счетчик злементов]

И в конце замен "вывести кол-во найденных тегов speed".

Можно еще через каждые 5000 замен делать паузу несколько секунд.

Comment: а в `<speed>ggg190hhh</speed>` может быть только одно 190 или несколько? если одно, что см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// #r "System.Xml.Linq"
// #r "System.Windows.Forms"

using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;

Task Process(string file, string srcXml, string trgXml, Action<int> cb) {
    var sc = SynchronizationContext.Current;   // запомнили основной поток
    return Task.Run(() => {   // выполняется в отдельном потоке
        var e = XElement.Load(srcXml);
        var c = 0;
        if (e.Descendants("speed").FirstOrDefault() == null) return;
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(file)) {
            sc.Send(v => cb((int) v), c++);  // передаем в основной поток
            foreach (var s in e.Descendants("speed"))
                if (s.Value.Contains(line))
                    s.Value = s.Value.Replace(line, "11111");
        }
        e.Save(trgXml);
    });
}
```

---

```
// для проверки работы Process
var f = new Form();
var s = new StatusStrip() { Parent = f };
var p = new ToolStripStatusLabel();
s.Items.Add(p);
f.Menu = new MainMenu();
f.Menu.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Start", (s,e) => {
    Process(
        @"C:\Temp\file.txt",
        @"C:\Temp\cars.xml",
        @"c:\temp\cars.new.xml",
        count => p.Text = count.ToString() // выводим количество обработанных строк
        ).ContinueWith(t =>
            MessageBox.Show("Completed " + t.Exception));
}));
f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34642/discussion-on-answer-by-stack-----xml----).